# How can i solve that question

Tags: probability

In a certain parking lot , there are 2 silver cars, 3 blue cars, 4 red cars , and 3 white cars. There are no other cars in the parking lot. What is the probability that a randomly car from the parking lot is not blue

Comment: It is easier if you ask first: 'What is the probability that a car picked is blue?'

Comment: How many cars are in the lot?  How many cars are not blue?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $P(\text{The car not being blue})=1-P(\text{the car being blue}).$